# How to share same data among two same component called twice on the same html template

Tags: node.js, angular, components

I have created a pagination component that I am using above and below a table.

> Issue is they create different memory reference for each call.

and hence creating a contradicting view as below:-

**Above Table**

[image]

**Below Table**

[image]

As we can see the Data on the html is same and `8` number is showing active on both but the array hold by both components contains different data.
How can I mirror both the components and make sure they share same data?

any help would be great thanks!

Comment: what did you try? how is this built?

Comment: @joshvito I tried to search the solution and didn't find one and clearly question posses the reason on how it is build!

Comment: I don't mind ppl downvoting my question unless I keep sharing and gathering knowledge on new issues!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you move the data to a service, then both instances of the component can share the same instance of the service and hence share the same data.

Would that work for you?

Here is an example service I have that shares these two values between multiple components:

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ProductParameterService {
  showImage: boolean;
  filterBy: string;

  constructor() { }

}
```

The class that uses the service then gets and sets the property into the service.

**Class that uses the service**

```
get showImage(): boolean {
    return this.productParameterService.showImage;
}
set showImage(value: boolean) {
    this.productParameterService.showImage = value;
}
```

Comment: ^Agree with this.

Comment: how this will create communication between two components?

Comment: Either instance of your pagination component can set the value into the service if the value is changed by the user. Since, in the above example, the showImage and filterBy properties are bound in the UI, change detection will automatically notify the components when a value is changed and their bindings are re-evaluated ... causing the getters to be called ... which gets the shared value from the service.

Comment: I have a plunker that demonstrates it here: https://plnkr.co/edit/KT4JLmpcwGBM2xdZQeI9?p=preview This plunker is two routed components, but the concept is the same for two "child" components.

Comment: upvoted! thanks for taking time for clarifying things, just last thing in your plunker you have created get and set methods inside a and b class components or they should be in data service?

Comment: if I open 2 different pages in the same browser this will change the pagination on other page also, this could create an issue

Comment: Maybe define a unique Id for each page set and make the shared data into an array? (Something like how route tracing is done.)

Comment: I always believed if you do too much you are doing it wrong..there must be an easy way!